# Cómo convierto un tf.Variable a numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

¿Cómo convierto una variable de *Tensorflow* a *Numpy*?

```
var1 = tf.Variable(4.0)
```

Quiero `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

*Tensorflow* utiliza bastante *Numpy* por lo que suele haber un gran polimorfismo entre ambas librerías.

Las variables tienen el método `.numpy()` que las convierte directamente a un array de *numpy*.

```
import tensorflow as tf
va1 = tf.Variable(4.)

#Convertimos a numpy
va1.numpy()
```